# Is this a valid answer for this NFA to DFA conversion

Tags: automata

I have to convert this NFA  to a DFA:

[image]

I used this technique : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-fk9o46oVY to get a DFA but i would like to validate with someone who has more experience if my result is good since my result doesn't look "pretty". Also how can i confirm it's a good solution ?

I would really appreciate, thank you.

Here's my result :

[image]

Comment: I see a few errors. The $a$ transition from $\{1,2\}$ should go to $\{2,3,4\}$, and the $a$ transition from $\{1,2,4\}$ should go to $\{1,2,3,4\}$. I did the conversion hastily and don’t guarantee it, but I get states $\{2,3,4\}$ and $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and don’t get $\{3,4\}, $\{1,3,4\}$ and $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott i edited my solution, i realized my mistake is this better ? Thanks for reply. P is the dead end

Comment: That agrees with my quick and dirty effort.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Nice, great thanks a lot for validating :) doing exercises without the solutions isn't always easy haha

Comment: You’re welcome. Yes, that does make it a bit harder.